# Using deprecated classes from AOSP in app locally

Tags: java, android

This may sound a little bit dumb question but I can't I figure out how to use the Android API classes that has already been deprecated. Recently I was going through [KeyboardView API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView) of android which has been deprecated in API level 29. There's a deprecation notice attached like this:

> This class is deprecated because this is just a convenient UI widget
>   class that application developers can re-implement on top of existing
>   public APIs. If you have already depended on this class, consider
>   copying the implementation from AOSP into your project or re-implementing a similar widget by yourselves

I would like to use Keyboard and KeyboardView classes but they are deprecated and there are no better solution for me. I have to write all these classes from scratch if I want to go the second suggested method 're-implementing a similar widget by yourselves'. Also I don't want to use  `@SuppressWarnings(“deprecation”)` because this may create problems in future android versions if these classes get discontinued. Is there any way I can integrate [these classes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/inputmethodservice) from AOSP since they are core classes.

Comment: You can grab those classes from the AOSP, rename the package they're in, and use that.  I will say having made keyboards in the past-  they're almost useless.  Unless you're doing very basic stuff, you'll quickly need totally custom solutions anyway.  Nobody writing a serious keyboard uses them.

Comment: @GabeSechan yeah, that makes sense but I have very minimal use case for the keyboard so writing these classes from start seems a lot of pain given the use case.